# building OpenCV as deb package: CPackDeb: file utility is not available

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm building OpenCV 4.1 as a deb package on Ubuntu 18.04. After success in building libraries. I'm calling `make package` and getting the following error:

`CPack: Create package
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake:622 (message):
  CPackDeb: file utility is not available.  CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS
  and CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_GENERATE_SHLIBS options are not available.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake:1119 (cpack_deb_prepare_package_vars)`

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: The error message is about absence of [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility. You need to install it for being able to pack the project.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard about the "file" package in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just need to install `file` package: `apt install file`